# adding opaic Jlabel to transparent Jdialog?

Tags: java, swing

Please run the code, the code is developed in netbeans using drag and drop method and please help me.. what i want is to display the power button as opaic and the rest of the JDialog opaic.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class quicklaunchApp extends java.awt.Dialog {

    int xMouse,yMouse;
    public quicklaunchApp(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();

       this.setOpacity(0.3f);


       this.Buttonpower.setOpaque(false);
    }


    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        Buttonpower = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Background = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(380, 140));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(380, 140));
        setUndecorated(true);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                closeDialog(evt);
            }
        });
        setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        Buttonpower.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Button_default.png"))); // NOI18N
        Buttonpower.setToolTipText("");
        Buttonpower.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ButtonpowerMouseClicked(evt);
            }
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ButtonpowerMouseEntered(evt);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ButtonpowerMouseExited(evt);
            }
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ButtonpowerMousePressed(evt);
            }
            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ButtonpowerMouseReleased(evt);
            }
        });
        add(Buttonpower, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 40, -1, -1));

        Background.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Background_default.png"))); // NOI18N
        Background.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                BackgroundMouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });
        Background.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                BackgroundMouseEntered(evt);
            }
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                BackgroundMouseExited(evt);
            }
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                BackgroundMousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        add(Background, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 380, 140));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    private void closeDialog(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                             
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
    }                            

    private void BackgroundMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
      int x = evt.getXOnScreen();
      int y = evt.getYOnScreen();
      this.setLocation(x-xMouse, y-yMouse);
    }                                       

    private void BackgroundMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
      xMouse = evt.getX();
      yMouse = evt.getY();
    }                                       

    private void BackgroundMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        

    }                                       

    private void BackgroundMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       


    }                                      

    private void ButtonpowerMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
      ImageIcon II = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Button_hover.png"));
      Buttonpower.setIcon(II);

    }                                        

    private void ButtonpowerMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
       ImageIcon II = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Button_pressed.png"));
       Buttonpower.setIcon(II);
    }                                        

    private void ButtonpowerMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        

    private void ButtonpowerMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
       ImageIcon II = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Button_hover.png"));
       Buttonpower.setIcon(II);
    }                                         

    private void ButtonpowerMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
      ImageIcon II = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Button_default.png"));
      Buttonpower.setIcon(II);


    }                                       


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                quicklaunchApp dialog = new quicklaunchApp(new java.awt.Frame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel Background;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Buttonpower;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Call setOpaque(true) on the label and setUndecorated(false) and setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)) on the frame to make it transparent

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow the [Java conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `this.setOpacity(0.3f);` to `this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));`.  If you want the button to opaque, then use `this.Buttonpower.setOpaque(true)`

I'd also discourage you from using `JLabel` this way and use a `JButton` instead, since you've basically re-implemented the basic functionality anyway.

Something like...

```
Buttonpower = new javax.swing.JButton("Stop this");
Buttonpower.setBorderPainted(false);
Buttonpower.setContentAreaFilled(false);
Buttonpower.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Button_default.png"))); // NOI18N
Buttonpower.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Button_hover.png")));
Buttonpower.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Button_pressed.png")));
Buttonpower.setRolloverEnabled(true);
```